# Get Each Character From Output - Java

Tags: java, string

Right now I have a program that puts an inputted expression into Postfix Evaluation. Below is a copy of my console.

```
Enter an expression: ((5*2-1)/6+14/3)*(2*3-5)+7/2
5 2 * 1 - 6 / 14 3 / + 2 3 * 5 - * 7 2 / +
```

I now need to walk through the output, however this output is just a bunch of *System.out.print* 's put together. I tried using a stringBuilder however it cant tell the difference between *14* and a *1 and 4*. 

Is there anyway I can go through each character of this output? I need to put these numbers into a stack.

Comment: override tostring maybe?

Comment: Add some delimiter so you can tell the difference between 14 and a 1 and 4?

Comment: Yes ... yourExpessionString.toCharArray() and then use Characher.isDigit(ch)

Comment: Please provide us some code for how you generate your output. That's where you want to graft in the code you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.split() and if you need only numbers regular expression.

Here is an Example:

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

            String str = "1 * 2 3 / 4 5 6";
            String[] arr = str.split(" ", str.length());

            for (int i=0;i < arr.length;i++)
                System.out.println(arr[i] + "is diggit? " + arr[i].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));

        }
    }
```

str holds the long String. arr will hold the split sub strings.

you just need to make sure that each sub string differ one space from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you deleted your code while I was reading it, but here's a conceptually developed answer.

As you input every character, you want to push that to the stack.

The unique scenario you've mentioned `14` is unique in that it's two characters.

So what you would want to do is track if the last character was ALSO a number.

Here's a rough pseudo. Your stack should be all Strings to support this.

```
//unique case for digit
if(s.charAt(0).isDigit()) {
    //check to see if the String at the top of a stack is a number by peeking at its first character
    if(stack.peek().charAt(0).isDigit()) { 
        int i = Integer.parseInt(stack.pop()) * 10;
        //we want to increment the entire String by 10, so a 1 -> 10
        i = i + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)); //add the last digit, so 10 + 4 = 14
        stack.push(Integer.toString(i)); //put the thing back on the stack
    }
    else {
        //handle normally
        stack.push(s.substring(0,1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you need to parse the actual string?

If so, then what you do is, create a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, and wherever you put `System.out.print` in your code, append the buffer - including the spaces, which are what will help you differentiate between 1 4 and 14. Then you can convert that to a String. Then you can parse the String by splitting it by the spaces. Then iterate through the resulting String array.

If there is no reason for you to use the actual full string, you can instead use a `List` object and just `add` to it in the same places in the code. In this case, you don't need the spaces. Then you'll be able to simply iterate through the list.

You'll still be able to print you output - by printing the elements in the list.